# Different JavaScript behavior in Chrome and Firefox for form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, forms

I had this snippet of JavaScript on my website for a while.  Its purpose is to prevent double click submissions by immediately clearing the input file after the form was submitted.  It used to work fine.  Today I tested it and for some reason Chrome submits an empty string as a file, but Firefox submits the file first and then clears it afterward, as expected.  Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

```
$('#uploadform').submit(function (e) {
    if ($('#file').val().length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    this.submit();
    $('#file').val('');
});
```

Comment: What does your `submit` function look like?

Comment: `Submit` may be an asynchronous function, which means it may get executed after the value has been cleared.

Comment: @KeVin http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Comment: @KeVin This appears to be the `<form>` element's own [`submit` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-submit), since the code is a jQuery `submit` handler (so it could only be attached to a `<form>` object), so the `this` object supplied by jQuery must be that same `<form>` object.

Comment: I assume the submit event is processed in the next tick, after you cleared the field. Maybe Firefox collects the values when `submit` is called and Chrome doesn't. Double submission is often prevent by simply disabling the submit button. Alternatively, try `setTimeout(function() { $('#file').val(''); }, 0);`.

Comment: Does moving `e.preventDefault()` to the end help?

Comment: Is there anyway to call submit() synchronously? @KeVin moving to the end didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are experiencing a race condition, where the form submission is happening after the value has been cleared. This behavior may be different across browsers. Considering as you are submitting the form without ajax, the form will be cleared automatically once the page reloads. To prevent multiple submissions, you can disable the submit button:

```
 $("#submit-button").attr("disabled","disabled");
```